# Kodaira dimension elliptic K3s

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I can't find a reference for this, so hopefully this isn't too trivial.

By the classification of surfaces by Kodaira dimension, elliptic surfaces have $\kappa = 1$ while K3 surfaces fall into the category of $\kappa = 0$.  However, elliptic K3 surfaces exist.  What would the Kodaira dimension be for such a variety?

I'm not sure if there is a distinction in the definition of an elliptic K3 compared to a general elliptic surface --- i.e., they are both defined to have an elliptic fibration.  An elliptic K3 doesn't seem to be "more" elliptic than it is a K3 surface, and conversely.

Comment: All surfaces with $\kappa=1$ are elliptic, but there are many elliptic surfaces which do not have $\kappa=1$, like K3, Enriques, Abelian surfaces etc.